# Error connecting to mongoDB database from dart web

Tags: mongodb, dart

I'm unable to connect to a mongodb database from a dart application.
I can connect only from terminal and from Compass

I've tried to run a simple example of connecting mongodb database from Dart (see the simple code below):

```
import 'package:mongo_dart/mongo_dart.dart';

void main() async {

Db db = new Db("mongodb://localhost:27017/test");
await db.open(); 
print('Connection succeeded!');
//the test database is accessible from Compass or terminal
//localhost:27017 works well   
}

await db.open() throws that error:
dart_sdk.js:5822 Uncaught Error: Unsupported operation: Socket 
constructor
at Object.dart.throw (dart_sdk.js:4537)
at Function._connect (dart_sdk.js:52279)
at Function.connect (dart_sdk.js:52264)
at mongo_dart._Connection.new.connect (connection.dart:56)
at mongo_dart._ConnectionManager.new._connect 
(connection_manager.dart:23)
at _connect.next (<anonymous>)
at runBody (dart_sdk.js:22269)
at Object.async.async (dart_sdk.js:22297)
at mongo_dart._ConnectionManager.new.[_connect] 
(connection_manager.dart:22)
at connection_manager.dart:58
at dart_sdk.js:23887
```

Answer (score 1):

`mongo_dart.dart` [imports `dart:io`](https://github.com/mongo-dart/mongo_dart/blob/6caef8f2f5649f02d673c3162bf80c4f5bb65247/lib/mongo_dart.dart#L10) and therefore cannot be used on the web. This package mentions that is is server side.

With the latest `build_web_compilers` this should be a build time error instead of a runtime error.

You'll need to find, or write, a package for mongoDB that uses `dart:html` instead of `dart:io`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Indeed, if I run the dart file from the terminal I have no errors.